# Can I create 2 XIBs for one view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib, uisegmentedcontrol

Basically, what I want to do is,

I want to load 2 different XIB files on each click of Segmented control

Is it possible to load 2 different XIB files?

for eg:

When I click on `View 1` my  1st XIB should be loaded and when i click on `View 2` my 2nd XIB should be loaded.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can this using xib like this bellow:-

- Add two `UIView` or `UIsegmentController`  and connect it's IBOutLate like bellow image .

[image]

- In `viewDidLoad` secondView put as a hidden True like bellow:-

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {   
      myview1.hidden=FALSE;
      myview2.hidden=TRUE;

      [super viewDidLoad];
  }
  ```

Put segment control **ValueChange** Action and connect with Segment control as a ValueChange:-

[image]

```
-(IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged{
    switch (seg.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            myview1.hidden=FALSE;
            myview2.hidden=TRUE;
            break;
        case 1:
             myview1.hidden=TRUE;
             myview2.hidden=FALSE;
            break;
               default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Now run you Project it's look like :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can create two view inside the same `nib/xib` file and add particular `view` on click `Segemented control`
One view already has `outlet` in controller class and for other view create a `IBOutlet` and use.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your image, I can see two view within same xib. What you want to do is called load two different view from same xib.

you need to use [NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:] method to achieve this.

```
NSArray *nib =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXIBName" owner:self options:nil];
```

Array nib will hold all views under given XIB. You can iterate/filter, and then load desired view on segment control click.